# Derivative with multiple summation operators

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, derivations

I have a defined utility function as Eq.(1), and I am seeking the minimized utility subjects to some constraints. The notation used is as following:
\linebreak 
$V$ is the set of nodes, $v_i\in V$; $O$ is content set within each node, $o_k\in O$; $o_k$ represents the $k^{th}$ item; $w$ is demand matrix, $w_{i,k}$ is the demand of $o_k$ on $v_i$, requests per seconds; $x_{i,k}$ represents whether $v_i$ caches $o_k$ locally; $y_{i,j,k}$ represents whether $v_i$ retrieves $o_k$ from the neighboring node $v_j$, and $v_j\in V$; $l_{i,j}$ is the length of the shortest path between nodes $v_i$ and $v_j$. For the variables $x_{i,k}$ and $y_{i,j,k}$, I am seeking for $min(U)$ subject the constraints (2) to (6). $u_i^0$ and $C_i$, are constant.

\begin{equation}
\label{eqn_utility}
U = \sum\limits_{v_i\in V} [-ln(\sum\limits_{o_k\in O} w_{i,k}x_{i,k} +\sum\limits_{o_k\in O}\sum\limits_{v_j\in V} \frac{w_{i,k}}{l_{i,j}}y_{i,j,k}-u_i^0)]
\qquad(1)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eqn_constrait1}
\sum\limits_{o_k\in O} x_{i,k} \leq C_i, \forall v_i\in V
\qquad(2)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eqn_constrait2}
\sum\limits_{v_j\in V} y_{i,j,k} \leq 1, \forall v_j\in V, o_k\in O
\qquad(3)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eqn_constrait3}
x_{i,k}\in {\big\{ 0,1 \big\} }, \forall v_i\in V, o_k\in O
\qquad(4)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eqn_constrait4}
y_{i,j,k}\in {\big\{ 0,1 \big\} }, \forall v_i\in V, v_j\in V, o_k\in O
\qquad(5)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eqn_constrait5}
y_{i,j,k} \leq x_{j,k}, \forall v_i\in V, v_j\in V, o_k\in O
\qquad(6)
\end{equation}

Bring the constraint (6) into (1), applying Lagrangian dual relaxation, I have,

\begin{align}
\label{eqn_Lagrangian}
L(x,y,\lambda) = \sum\limits_{v_i\in V} [-ln(\sum\limits_{o_k\in O} w_{i,k}x_{i,k} +\sum\limits_{o_k\in O}\sum\limits_{v_j\in V} \frac{w_{i,k}}{l_{i,j}}y_{i,j,k}-u_i^0) \nonumber\\
 +\sum\limits_{v_j\in V}\sum\limits_{o_k\in O} \lambda_{i,j,k}(y_{i,j,k}-x_{j,k})]
\qquad(7)
\end{align}

Let $x^*$ and $y^*$ be the minimizers for the Lagrangian (7) over all $x$ and $y$. Then the dual function (7) can be rewritten as $d(\lambda)=L(x^*,y^*,\lambda)$. By maximizing the dual function, the optimal solution for the primal problem (1) can be derived from the optimal solution as  $max(d(\lambda)=L(x^*,y^*,\lambda))$. Then, the projected subgradient method will be used to obtain $x$, $y$ and $\lambda$ for the optimum.
\linebreak
However, when I derived the first order sub differential of the Eq(7), to obtain the expression of $x^*$ and $y^*$, I am not sure how to deal with the case of multiple summation operators involved.
\linebreak
Let  $\frac {\partial L(x,y,\lambda)} {\partial x_{i,k} }=0$, I have,

\begin{align}
\label{eqn_derivative1}
\frac {\partial L(x,y,\lambda)} {\partial x_{i,k} } =- \sum\limits_{v_i\in V} \frac {\sum\limits_{o_k\in O} w_{i,k}x_{i,k}} {\sum\limits_{o_k\in O} w_{i,k}x_{i,k} +\sum\limits_{o_k\in O}\sum\limits_{v_j\in V} \frac{w_{i,k}}{l_{i,j}}y_{i,j,k}-u_i^0} \nonumber\\
 -\sum\limits_{v_i\in V}\sum\limits_{v_j\in V}\sum\limits_{o_k\in O} \lambda_{i,j,k}(y_{i,j,k}-x_{j,k})=0
\qquad(8)
\end{align}

and then I don’t know what is the next step to obtain $x^*=$? 
Similarly, let  $\frac {\partial L(x,y,\lambda)} {\partial y_{i,j,k} }=0$, and then $y^*=$?

Can anyone help with this?

Many thanks.

Comment: this question receives little helpful response, I guess because it is not clear what type of answer you seek; you have some complicated function in a high-dimensional landscape and wish to find a (local? global?) minimum; I don't think you can hope for some closed form answer, you'll have to search numerically for an extremum by following lines of descent.